# After `chown -R` git is super slow

Tags: bash, git, ownership

I have a massive GIT project with several GIT submodules inside. I recursively changed ownership(`chown -r`) from `root` to my user for each file in my project.

Now any git command takes a lot of time to complete and seems to use 99% CPU. What is the issue?

I did `sudo chown -R my_user my_project/`

**UPDATE**

This seems not to be only GIT related, other terminal commands take a lot of time too. `top` shows me 100% git usage for like 15 seconds instead of usual 0-1 seconds.

Comment: not your `chown -r` command.

Comment: @A.B. please elaborate more.

Comment: `git` does not care who owns the files, as long as it can access the files.

Comment: Watch the output of `top` or `htop` and the I/O activities.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: you said __massive__; maybe before you have _cached_  files that now, after the ownership change ,are not anymore seen as the same...  or something as _nepomuk_ / _akonadi_ /_updatedb_ is indexing all as new. Check with `top` `htop`...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the command

```
sudo chown -R my_user my_project/
```

you have changed **all** files in a **huge** (as you said) repository, therefore your KDE/GNOME/Unity file indexer has a lot of work now. Give the process time to complete its work. Go and drink a coffee **;)**

To watch what's happening from an Input/output perspective, install `iotop` via:

```
sudo apt-get install iotop
```

and watch the output of:

```
sudo iotop
```

Comment: Why? `git` only check the modes.

Comment: That probably is the reason. Its the only one I can think of too. Also I like coffee so I've already have one made for myself :))

Comment: @lukas.pukenis What about the coffee and `top`, `htop` response?  Who's wasting your resources? :-) Remember that you can always exclude paths from the file indexer, and add again when you will go to eat or to sleep !

Comment: @Hastur when I type like `git status` I have 100% cpu usage for like 15seconds instead of `0..1` seconds. Memory is not an issue and IO activity is low :/

Comment: @lukas.pukenis I shouldn't  assert it so easily,  with no doubt as you do: if there are many other processes that are opening/blocking that files (remember the magic word __massive__ ),  you can need more time then before.  Please check and update who is using your HDD and your CPU time. None can find from here the answer and it is over there. Good hunt and coffee. BTW if you pause/stop  the indexer and when you give the command it's faster you find your guilty. :-) Good hunt and coffee...